# ng-if="x" gets rendered, ng-if="x != false" is not rendered?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a Task to hide a Progress Bar if there are no steps.

To test it, i set the var to `productBarSteps = []`

If i now try to test it, i get unexpected results:

`<div data-ng-if="productBarSteps">..content..</div>`

result: div is shown

`<div data-ng-if="productBarSteps != false">..content</div>`

result: div is not shown

I expected both divs to be not shown, can anyone help me understand? what am i missing? shouldn't `true` and `not false` result in the same?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since it is an array, it is always true. you should use `productBarSteps.length` for checking.

Comment: ng-if means also if that variable is defined
so if you have a variable with that name ng-if will be true for this reason it is reccomended to use an expression like ng-if value === true

Comment: You have defined an empty array and checking for boolean. Try this productBarSteps != []

Comment: @FarukT No, the value of that variable also needs to be truthy. In fact, `ng-if` evaluates an *expression*, so the *expression* must be truthy.

Comment: @callback but as i said in the original post, why is the one div rendered and the other not? seems like the array is not always true, when i test it on `!= false`..i don't get it.

@arunjai i also tried that, it still was visible :/